# i am trying this multi threaded code to understand. can anyone help me understand the "print message" part. i am posting the code herewith

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

i am trying this multi threaded code to understand. can anyone help me understand the "print message" part. i am posting the code herewith

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <linux/in.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    typedef struct
    {
        int sock;
        struct sockaddr address;
        int addr_len;
    } connection_t;

    void * process(void * ptr)
    {
        char * buffer;
        int len;
        connection_t * conn;
        long addr = 0;

        if (!ptr) pthread_exit(0); 
        conn = (connection_t *)ptr;


        read(conn->sock, &len, sizeof(int));
        if (len > 0)
        {
            addr = (long)((struct sockaddr_in *)&conn->address)->sin_addr.s_addr;
            buffer = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
            buffer[len] = 0;

            read(conn->sock, buffer, len);

            /* print message */
            printf("%d.%d.%d.%d: %s\n",
                (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
                (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
                (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
                (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff),
                buffer);
            free(buffer);
        }


        close(conn->sock);
        free(conn);
        pthread_exit(0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...

      return 0;
        }
```

i know we are trying to print the data from the buffer but how is all this shift operator and' & 0xff' part helping ?? :

```
printf("%d.%d.%d.%d: %s\n",
                (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
                (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
                (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
                (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff),
                buffer);
```

can't we just simply use printf statement like this:

```
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

to read from the buffer??

Comment: The is no "explain the code" site. Just that: the code contains "problematic" parts (e.g. implementation defined behaviour) and is not well written.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with multithreading, or with sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are splitting `addr`, which is expected to be 32-bit long but it is not always, to each octets.

```
printf("%d.%d.%d.%d: %s\n",
                (int)((addr      ) & 0xff), /* the least octet */
                (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff), /* the second least octet */
                (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff), /* the second most octet */
                (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff), /* the most octet */
                buffer); /* what is received */
```

You can use

```
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

if you don't want to know where the packet is sent.

Note that you should use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to initialize the buffer with zero or change

```
read(conn->sock, buffer, len);
```

to

```
{
    ssize_t readlen = read(conn->sock, buffer, len);
    if (readlen < 0) readlen = 0;
    buffer[readlen] = '\0';
}
```

before passing `buffer` to `printf()`. Otherwise, you may invoke *undefined behavior* for using buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized.